# Lispy way of running a function multiple times

Tags: common-lisp

I am using a function `d` to generate random numbers which I collect in a list and then average them:

```
 (/ (apply #'+ (list (d 6) (d 6) (d 6) (d 6) (d 6) (d 6))) 6.0)
```

I would like to run the function `(d n)` `i` times, add the returned values together, and then divide by `i`. `dotimes` does not return a value. How would I do this in Common Lisp?

Comment: If you posted a question "1 hour ago" and were able to post an answer "59 minutes ago", it seems like you might not have performed all the research that Stack Overflow questions are typically expected to exhibit.  See, e.g., [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1281433).  As Rainer points out, **dotimes** returns a value, and it's very clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: I had googled but couldn't define the search terms properly. I had gone on IRC and asked there, but hadn't had a reply in twenty minutes. I had gone through the inline documentation but couldn't find anything (due to being unable to define the search terms). I then posted it on SO, when a fine fellow on IRC popped up unexpectedly and gave me an answer. I thought I'd share that answer here for the benefit of the community. I had experimented with `dotimes` and got no return value (I was obviously doing it wrong). Just because I didn't write  diary entry doesn't mean I didn't do any research.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(defun r (n f arg)
  "Calls the function F N times with ARG. Returns
the arithmetic mean of the results."
  (/ (loop repeat n sum (funcall f arg))
     n))

(r 6 #'d 6)
```

> dotimes does not return a value.

it does:

```
CL-USER 21 > (let ((sum 0))
               (dotimes (i 10 sum)        ; <- sum is the return value
                 (incf sum (random 10))))
45
```

Answer (score 4):

A very kind soul on IRC gave me this solution:

`(loop repeat 6 collect (d 6))`